# 'not a subtype' error when parsing Json for TypeAheadFormField Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am using TypeAheadFormField to show suggestions to the user as they type, with data pulled from an API designed to autosuggest items.

I have isolated the issue and it is failing at the `suggestionsCallback:` stage, as the call is made. I have isolated it to the API call and the parsing of the data. I have tried lots of variations in the Class, call etc but can't get the error to go on running.

The error showing under text field(on simulator)

[image]

My Class (leaned down Quicktype.io) I have tried lots of versions and none worked for me. I am just trying to get the `address` value from the List `Items` to get it working

```
class Items {
    Items({
        required this.items,
    });

    List<Item>? items;
    
    factory Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Items(
        items: json["items"] == null ? null : List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
    );
}

class Item {
  final String address;

  const Item({
    required this.address,
  });

  static Item fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        address: json['address'],
      );
}
```

API returns in a Json List called `Items` (Have removed bulk of data for this example, just 'address' I want at the moment)

```
{"items":[{"title":"Buckingham Palace","address":{"label":"Buckingham Palace Road, London, SW1E 5, United Kingdom"}"title":"Buckingham Place, London, SW1E 6, United Kingdom","resultType":"street","address":{"label":"Buckingham Place, London, SW1E 6, United Kingdom"}...
```

My API call for the data

```
 class UserApi {
  static FutureOr<Iterable<Items>> getUserSuggestions(String query) async {

    final url = Uri.parse('https_call');
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final users = json.decode(response.body);

   *Fails Here*   return users.map((json) => Items.fromJson(json)).where((user) {
        final nameLower = user.address.toLowerCase();
        final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();

        return nameLower.contains(queryLower);
      }).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think that the json you provide us is incorrect.

I tried to fix it, so I made it like below:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Buckingham Palace",
            "address": {
                "label": "Buckingham Palace Road, London, SW1E 5, United Kingdom"
            },"title": "Buckingham Place, London, SW1E 6, United Kingdom",
            "resultType": "street",
            "address": {
                "label": "Buckingham Place, London, SW1E 6, United Kingdom"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And you can use the class below to parse it:

```dart
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final items = itemsFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Items itemsFromJson(String str) => Items.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String itemsToJson(Items data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Items {
    Items({
        this.items,
    });

    final List<Item> items;

    factory Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Items(
        items: json["items"] == null ? null : List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "items": items == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Item {
    Item({
        this.title,
        this.address,
        this.resultType,
    });

    final String title;
    final Address address;
    final String resultType;

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
        address: json["address"] == null ? null : Address.fromJson(json["address"]),
        resultType: json["resultType"] == null ? null : json["resultType"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title == null ? null : title,
        "address": address == null ? null : address.toJson(),
        "resultType": resultType == null ? null : resultType,
    };
}

class Address {
    Address({
        this.label,
    });

    final String label;

    factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Address(
        label: json["label"] == null ? null : json["label"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "label": label == null ? null : label,
    };
}
```